# How can I create spline function variables in Stata by hand?

Tags: stata, spline

I know there is, in Stata, a command called `mkspline` that generates cubic spline function. But I want to replicate my Stata output using other software, so I need to learn how to create these spline function variables.

If, say, I use a syntax like this :

```
mkspline age3sp = age, cubic knots(-13 -7 0 8 16)
```

How would you do it by hand ?

Comment: Note that `mkspline` is a command, not a function (in Stata the terms are **not** synonymous; edited accordingly). Moreover, it does more than create the ingredients for a cubic spline.

Answer (score 2):

I would read the Stata documentation for `mkspline` (see http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rmkspline.pdf for an online copy of the version included with Stata 14) and follow the guidance in the **Methods and formulas** section.